Centre of Mass for a flexible body
"Centre of Mass" is just a mathematical average of an object through which we can study the motion of that object.
If I try to lift a book by holding it at the edge or corner of the book, mg is assumed to be passing through the COM and the entire book stays in Equilibrium.
But when I lift the book by placing it on my finger, at its centre, the corners of the book bend downwards. Why are the corners bending (Moving) even COM isn't and when mg is balanced by Normal? And do the corners have their own COM which we need to support, for them not to bend?

Your statements are  too confused  for a simple answer. You need to understand the conditions of equilibrium of a rigid body to correct your first wrong assertion , and then to understand the difference between rigid and elastic bodies for your second.


when I lift the book by placing it on my finger, at its centre, the corners of the book bend downwards.

That's possible.

Why are the corners bending (Moving) even COM isn't and when mg is balanced by Normal?

Momentarily, $mg$ is not balanced.   The corners are not fully supported by your finger, so the normal is slightly less than $mg$.
Because a portion of the book is moving downward (the corners), the average mass of the book must therefore also be moving downward.   So the COM does move slightly as the corners move slightly.

And do the corners have their own COM which we need to support, for them not to bend?

Bending is a response to unequal forces across a body.   While simple position kinematics can be solved with COM and external force calculations, bending is not.
From a comment:

If Normal of the finger which is acting only at a point (Assuming acting only the COM) is slightly less than mg, then the entire book, as a whole, would accelerate down. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

First of all, the COM isn't a real physical object.   It's a mathematical point, and that point may not even be within the borders of the object.    So the normal is not acting "on the COM" at all.   It's acting at a point on the boundary of the book.   It might be in line with the COM so that no torques arise, but that is all.
As we have already decided the book is not completely rigid, it is unclear what you mean by "the book as a whole would accelerate".   It is only required for some parts of the book to accelerate (and not others) for the COM to accelerate.
Instead of a book, let's make the example more extreme.   Imagine you have a square piece of cloth.   You place this cloth horizontally centered on the tip of your finger.
Since the cloth is horizontal, the COM must be in the plane of the cloth.   Gravity then pulls the edges of the cloth down over your finger.   As the cloth deforms, the COM is now much lower than before.   The COM has accelerated downward even though your finger is supporting the center of the cloth.  The COM will now be well below the contact point of the finger and cloth.
The reason is that the normal force from your finger was not equal to $mg$ of the cloth.   The corners were unsupported and their weight was not transmitted to the rest of the cloth initially.   Only after they fell and were hanging down did their weight appear.  During the period of time that the normal force was less than $mg$, the COM of the cloth was accelerating downward.
The same is happening (to a smaller extent) with the flexible corners of the book.

"The corners are not fully supported by your finger, so the normal is slightly less than mg." If Normal of the finger which is acting only at a point (Assuming acting only the COM) is slightly less than mg, then the entire book, as a whole, would accelerate down. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

I added a bit to the answer to address that comment.

Treating the weight of an object as a single force that passes through its centre of mass is a simplification that can be useful in some scenarios, but not useful in others. In particular, if an object is not rigid then the position of its centre of mass moves as its shape changes. The amount by which the centre of mass moves depends on where and how the object is supported and how stiff or flexible it is. In general, you have to consider the effect of gravity, external support forces and also internal forces on each individual element of the object - beam theory is an example of how this works.

You seem to be conflating static equilibrium concepts with mechanics of materials concepts.
Static equilibrium does not preclude bending. It just requires the sum of the moments and sum of the forces be zero so that there will be no angular or linear acceleration.
Unless the book is an ideal rigid body, bending can occur in both your equilibrium scenarios. For the holding scenario (where your hand is providing a cantilever type support) the free end of the book will bend downwards, just like a cantilever supported beam. For the finger at the COM scenario the corners of the book will bend downwards.
The "movement" you describe is a transient phenomena that occurs until internal stresses equilibriate, after which the movement ceases (unless the structure fails)
Hope this helps.
